# How to find most 3 largest columns from 4 columns

Tags: mysql

I need to return most 3 largest marks from quiz_1, quiz_2, quiz_3, quiz_4 in this mysql table. How to do that.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAmKU.png)

Comment: How should the result look like?

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor l design. Consider revising your schema. And then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Find the value to be ejected using LEAST(). Use CASE for to select current/next column depends on found least value is in the next column or not. May work incorrectly if 2 or more columns contains the same least value.

Answer (score 1):

I would set up the table like this:

```
 stu_id quiz_number quiz_points
 ------ ----------- -----------
 BST377 1           80
 BST377 2           73
 BST377 3           78
 BST377 4           85
```

What will you do if one day there is a fifth quiz? Or a sixth quiz?
Add a column in the table here every time?

And for your query use top n with Grouping with row_number():

http://www.silota.com/docs/recipes/sql-top-n-group.html